# Microsoft SQL Dynamic Query Column Name In IIF Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

```
@ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)

@ColumnName = 'Column1'

IIF (Table1.' + @ColumnName + 'IS NULL, 0, Table1.' + @ColumnName + ') as Result
```

In a dynamic query, I am trying to find out if the value of the selected field is null. The dynamic SQL query works fine using the `@ColumnName` in all the other sub-queries, however I had to pull out this one line to get it to work.

Now if I run this query as a standard SQL statement and hard-code the column name it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a space

```
@ColumnName + 'IS NULL
               ^-----------------here
```

Comment: Wow totally missed that.  That's one of the thing I wish they would fix in a future build.  A way to type out Dynamic SQL Statements that are strongly typed.  Thanks!